# How to create project by api, cli or management commands

Tags: weblate

I need programatically create new **empty** (or not) project. How can i do that?
Then i use [import-json](https://docs.weblate.org/en/latest/admin/management.html#import-json) to create components.

The documentation has [import-project](https://docs.weblate.org/en/latest/admin/management.html#import-project) command, but

> < project > names an existing project, into which the components should be imported.

Comment: Also created [issue](https://github.com/WeblateOrg/weblate/issues/1674)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can do that with **weblate shell** or **./manage.py shell**

```
from weblate.trans.models import Project
project = Project.objects.create(
            name='Test',
            slug='test',
            web='https://weblate.org/'
)
project.save()
```

Also you can exec script from file

> weblate shell < create_project.py